# Automate ajax requests with HTML5 data- attributes

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

Let's say I have a form:

```
<form>
  ...   
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and I want it to be submitted normally, but if the user has javascript enabled, the form should be submitted using javascript ($.ajax).

Because I have many forms like this one, I was thinking I could automate the process of handling ajax requests with jquery.

so I'm adding `data-ajax-event="login"` to the form.

Then I'm calling the $.ajax thing on all elements that have that attribute, send a request to `site.com/ajax/` with the "ajax-event" parameter and all the form fields.

This is ok so far, but a problem appears when I have to get the response and decide what message should I display and where (do changes to the DOM from the $.ajax complete function).

For example, the login response would send a json object with errors when there are login errors, or a URL where to redirect on success. Other forms may send HTML or whatever.

Do you know how could I automate that process too? I'm not asking for any specific solution. Just ideas on how should I approach this. Or maybe examples of frameworks that are doing stuff like this...

Right now I have everything split, all the output is done from the templates, and all the processing inside the PHP. For the ajax thing to work I have to do some processing inside the templates, and I don't like the idea of doing that

Comment: How about a similar mechanism for handling responses? Since you're using the "data-ajax-event" along with the request data sent to the server, why not add a response-type field as well to the response data, so jQuery could parse the response and determine how and/or where to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this just by adding an abstraction level. The idea is that whenever you will send information to the server, the JS code will not be hard coded to any specific form. It will just loop over all of the forms fields and send their values to the server. On the server side you can process the request and figure out what are the errors, if any. Then you can return them by binding the error to a specific field:

```
{
  ...,
  errors: {
     "field-1": "error message",
     "field-2": "error message",
     ...
  }
}
```

Then you can just loop over the errors and for each key within the `errors` find the corresponding field in the DOM and add an error message near it.

**Other thoughts**

It is usually a good idea to setup a captcha on web site forms to avoid spam submissions. So I would highly recommend in addition to automatically processing the form, also automate the captcha validation. Also it will not hurt to add a csrf validation. You can read more about it at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).